# Node.js + Joi how to display a custom error messages?

Tags: node.js, joi

It seems pretty straight forward to validate user's input in Node.js RESTapi with `Joi`.

But the problem is that my app is not written in English.
That means I need to send a custom written messages to the frontend user.

I have googled for this and only found issues.

Maybe could someone give a solution for this?

This is the code I am using to validate with the `Joi` system:

```
    var schema = Joi.object().keys({
      firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required(),
      lastName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required()
      ..
    });

    Joi.validate(req.body, schema, function(err, value) {
      if (err) {
        return catched(err.details); 
      }
    });

    function catched(reject) {
      res.json({
        validData: false,
        errors: reject
      });
    }
```

Plus, is there a way to use `Joi` in client side?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting read about using Joi for front-facing error messages: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/546

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A solution I have found is to set:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().label("Your error message in here"),
  lastName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required()
  ..
});
```

Then print the `label` from the callback `error` variable

Comment: The "label" is only overrides the key name in error messages. While other solutions displayed how to customize the error message.

Comment: How do I print the lablel message as an object

Answer (score 114):

**Original answer**:

The current way (I personally find it better) is to use `.messages()` (or `.prefs({messages})`).

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const joiSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string()
    .min(2)
    .max(10)
    .required()
    .messages({
      'string.base': `"a" should be a type of 'text'`,
      'string.empty': `"a" cannot be an empty field`,
      'string.min': `"a" should have a minimum length of {#limit}`,
      'any.required': `"a" is a required field`
    })
});

const validationResult = joiSchema.validate({ a: 2 }, { abortEarly: false });
console.log(validationResult.error); // expecting ValidationError: "a" should be a type of 'text'
```

Usage of `.errors()` is [not recommended](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr) just to update default message with custom message.

`.prefs({ messages })` is an elaborate way to provide more options as preferences. The other options for prefs are taken directly from options of [.validate()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidatevalue-options)

Further read: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2158

---

**Update 1**: I saw that the above explanation did not work out for some folks, so I have put up some code to test yourself. Check it here: https://runkit.com/embed/fnfaq3j0z9l2

Also updated the code snippet shared previously to have details from package inclusion, to usage, to calling the actual validation method.

---

**Update 2**: The list of joi error types and their description (for `.messages()` - like string.base, array.unique, date.min etc..) is available [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#list-of-errors).

---

**Update 3**: Joi has [moved from hapi project](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411) to standalone: https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi.
Make sure you are using latest version (or at least above v17).

Comment: `TypeError: Joi.string(...).messages is not a function`

Comment: What version of Joi are you using? Please check it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi). Also, the documentation specifies the usage of `any.messages` [here](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#anymessagesmessages)

Comment: Benefit of this answer, is it also works properly with 3rd party packages such as `react-hook-form`

Comment: Just a heads up, the package @hapi/joi is now moved back to joi. Per the authors message here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi, "joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)"

Comment: @RvyPandey this looks like the answer I need but am having trouble. I posted new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070468/how-do-i-override-empty-rule-with-messages-in-joi-17. Thanks for any help!

Comment: To find the key e.g. string.base , All you need to check the type key in the default response and just copy and paste that key in messages functions and it would work

Answer (score 81):

Extending on [Ashish Kadam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854937/806975), if you have many different error types, you can check which type of error is present, and set its message accordingly:

### Joi v17.4.0

v17.4.0 uses `err.code`

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(errors => {
    errors.forEach(err => {
      switch (err.code) {
        case "any.empty":
          err.message = "Value should not be empty!";
          break;
        case "string.min":
          err.message = `Value should have at least ${err.local.limit} characters!`;
          break;
        case "string.max":
          err.message = `Value should have at most ${err.local.limit} characters!`;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
    return errors;
  }),
  // ...
});
```

You can check the list of errors here: [Joi 17.4.0 API Reference > Errors > List of errors](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/v17.4.0/API.md#list-of-errors)

### Joi v14.3.1

v14.3.1 uses `err.type`

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(errors => {
    errors.forEach(err => {
      switch (err.type) {
        case "any.empty":
          err.message = "Value should not be empty!";
          break;
        case "string.min":
          err.message = `Value should have at least ${err.context.limit} characters!`;
          break;
        case "string.max":
          err.message = `Value should have at most ${err.context.limit} characters!`;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
    return errors;
  }),
  // ...
});
```

You can check the list of errors here: [Joi 14.3.1 API Reference > Errors > List of errors](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#list-of-errors)

Also you can check the [`any.error`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#anyerrorerr-options) reference for more information. Quoting the docs:

> Overrides the default joi error with a custom error if the rule fails where:
>
> - `err` can be:
>
>   - an instance of `Error` - the override error.
>   - a `function(errors)`, taking an array of errors as argument, where it must either:
>
>     - return a `string` - substitutes the error message with this text
>     - return a single `object` or an `Array` of it, where:
>
>       - `type` - optional parameter providing the type of the error (eg. `number.min`).
>       - `message` - optional parameter if `template` is provided, containing the text of the error.
>       - `template` - optional parameter if `message` is provided, containing a template string, using the same format as usual joi language errors.
>       - `context` - optional parameter, to provide context to your error if you are using the `template`.
>     - return an `Error` - same as when you directly provide an `Error`, but you can customize the error message based on the errors.
> - `options`:
>
>   - `self` - Boolean value indicating whether the error handler should be used for all errors or only for errors occurring on this property (`true` value). This concept only makes sense for `array` or `object` schemas as other values don't have children. Defaults to `false`.

Comment: i liked this answer the most.

Comment: I've created a blog post regarding adding error code(s) to Hapi response based on this answer. Thanks for the solution. Anyone who's interested in can check it out at https://midnightcodr.github.io/2019/06/08/Add-error-code-s-to-Hapijs-validation-output/

Comment: excellent answer! - btw i used 
case "string.empty"
instead of 
case "any.empty",
saying about v17.4.0

Answer (score 43):

**Joi Version 14.0.0**

```
const SchemaValidation = {
  coins: Joi.number()
    .required()
    .error(() => {
      return {
        message: 'Coins is required.',
      };
    }),
  challenge_name: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .error(() => {
      return {
        message: 'Challenge name is required.',
      };
    }),
  challengeType: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .error(() => {
      return {
        message: 'Challenge type is required.',
      };
    }),
  challengeDescription: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .error(() => {
      return {
        message: 'Challenge description is required.',
      };
    }),
};
```

In **errors** object you can get, error type and change message according.

Comment: This is not right as error() must return an JS Error object.

Comment: not sure if this is the right way, but seems to work  `.error( err => { err[0].message= "Custom Error Message"; return err; } )`

Answer (score 36):

#### Using templates

I had to dig through the [source](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/lib/types/string.js#L688) to find an example of how to do context-dependent templating / formatting of messages since it doesn't seem to be documented:

```js
messages: {
  'string.alphanum': '{{#label}} must only contain alpha-numeric characters',
  'string.base': '{{#label}} must be a string',
  'string.base64': '{{#label}} must be a valid base64 string',
  'string.creditCard': '{{#label}} must be a credit card',
  'string.dataUri': '{{#label}} must be a valid dataUri string',
  'string.domain': '{{#label}} must contain a valid domain name',
  'string.email': '{{#label}} must be a valid email',
  'string.empty': '{{#label}} is not allowed to be empty',
  'string.guid': '{{#label}} must be a valid GUID',
  'string.hex': '{{#label}} must only contain hexadecimal characters',
  'string.hexAlign': '{{#label}} hex decoded representation must be byte aligned',
  'string.hostname': '{{#label}} must be a valid hostname',
  'string.ip': '{{#label}} must be a valid ip address with a {{#cidr}} CIDR',
  'string.ipVersion': '{{#label}} must be a valid ip address of one of the following versions {{#version}} with a {{#cidr}} CIDR',
  'string.isoDate': '{{#label}} must be in iso format',
  'string.isoDuration': '{{#label}} must be a valid ISO 8601 duration',
  'string.length': '{{#label}} length must be {{#limit}} characters long',
  'string.lowercase': '{{#label}} must only contain lowercase characters',
  'string.max': '{{#label}} length must be less than or equal to {{#limit}} characters long',
  'string.min': '{{#label}} length must be at least {{#limit}} characters long',
  'string.normalize': '{{#label}} must be unicode normalized in the {{#form}} form',
  'string.token': '{{#label}} must only contain alpha-numeric and underscore characters',
  'string.pattern.base': '{{#label}} with value {:[.]} fails to match the required pattern: {{#regex}}',
  'string.pattern.name': '{{#label}} with value {:[.]} fails to match the {{#name}} pattern',
  'string.pattern.invert.base': '{{#label}} with value {:[.]} matches the inverted pattern: {{#regex}}',
  'string.pattern.invert.name': '{{#label}} with value {:[.]} matches the inverted {{#name}} pattern',
  'string.trim': '{{#label}} must not have leading or trailing whitespace',
  'string.uri': '{{#label}} must be a valid uri',
  'string.uriCustomScheme': '{{#label}} must be a valid uri with a scheme matching the {{#scheme}} pattern',
  'string.uriRelativeOnly': '{{#label}} must be a valid relative uri',
  'string.uppercase': '{{#label}} must only contain uppercase characters'
}
```

An example of using a templated message:

```js
const Joi = require("joi");

const schema = Joi.object({
  nested: Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required().messages({
      "any.required": "{{#label}} is required!!",
      "string.empty": "{{#label}} can't be empty!!",
    }),
  }),
});

const result = schema.validate({
  nested: {
    // comment/uncomment to see the other message
    // name: "",
  },
});

console.log(result.error.details);
```

When using the template syntax, the context values that seem to be passed are something like the following, though specific rules / validators may pass more context:

```js
{
 ​key: "name", // this key, without ancestry
 ​label: `"nested.name"`, // full path with dots as separators, in quotes
 ​value: "", // the value that was validated
}
```

Comment: Their docs are just awful...

Answer (score 24):

You can use **.error(new Error('message'))**, And its work for me

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(new Error('Give your error message here for first name')),
  lastName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(new Error('Give your error message here for last name'))
  ..
});

Joi.validate(req.body, schema, function(err, value) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    return catched(err.message); 
  }
});
```

Comment: But it will bypass the `abortEarly` :(

Answer (score 11):

You can also show messages for a particular property

```
const Joi = require('Joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string()
      .min(2)
      .max(30)
      .required()
      .pattern(new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/))
      .message({"string.pattern.base":"Invalid username",
                "string.min":"minimum 2 character required",
                "string.max":"maximum 30 characters allowed"})
  });
```

You can refer this for message object keys.

```
messages: {
      'any.custom': [Object],
      'any.default': [Object],
      'any.failover': [Object],
      'any.invalid': [Object],
      'any.only': [Object],
      'any.ref': [Object],
      'any.required': [Object],
      'any.unknown': [Object],
      'string.alphanum': [Object],
      'string.base': [Object],
      'string.base64': [Object],
      'string.creditCard': [Object],
      'string.dataUri': [Object],
      'string.domain': [Object],
      'string.email': [Object],
      'string.empty': [Object],
      'string.guid': [Object],
      'string.hex': [Object],
      'string.hexAlign': [Object],
      'string.hostname': [Object],
      'string.ip': [Object],
      'string.ipVersion': [Object],
      'string.isoDate': [Object],
      'string.isoDuration': [Object],
      'string.length': [Object],
      'string.lowercase': [Object],
      'string.max': [Object],
      'string.min': [Object],
      'string.normalize': [Object],
      'string.token': [Object],
      'string.pattern.base': [Object],
      'string.pattern.name': [Object],
      'string.pattern.invert.base': [Object],
      'string.pattern.invert.name': [Object],
      'string.trim': [Object],
      'string.uri': [Object],
      'string.uriCustomScheme': [Object],
      'string.uriRelativeOnly': [Object],
      'string.uppercase': [Object]
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

**Solution to add custom messages:**
Simply add another chained function to throw error while defining your schema.
In your case

```
 firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(new Error('I am a custom error and I know it!')),
```

Rest will remain same.

**Solution to use Joi at client side**  (Your 2nd question)

[Joi-Browser](https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser)
is the package which enables usage of the same schema at the client side.

[Here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/546) is an interesting discussion you can have a look at.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Just call "message()" function :

```
firstName: Joi.string().message("Your custom message")
```

Answer (score 3):

> let schema = Joi.object({
>       foo: Joi.number().min(0)**.error(() => '"foo" requires a positive number')**
>   });

Docs [link](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr)

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version use message as.

```js
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().messages({
    "string.base": `"username" should be a type of 'text'`,
    "string.empty": `"username" cannot be an empty field`,
    "any.required": `"username" is a required.`,
  }),
  lastName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().messages({
    "string.base": `"lastName" should be a type of 'text'`,
    "string.empty": `"lastName" cannot be an empty field`,
    "any.required": `"lastName" is a required.`,
  }),
  [...]
});
```

Comment: i have question ... what is condition for email valid format

Answer (score 1):

```
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
   Joi.string().required().options({language: {any: {required: "First name is required"}}})
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: Joi.string(...).messages is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having a problem with

> ...messages is not a function

errors, you must install `joi` with `npm install @hapi/joi`, and importing it with `@hapi/joi`. I've made the mistake of installing `joi` without the `@hapi/` prefix and it took me a while to find the error.

Comment: Also, while requiring the module, specifying it as
const Joi = `require('@hapi/joi')` is necessary, if you have Joi installed globally.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who like me was looking to validate a number with a custom message, this is from the source code :

```
'number.base': '{{#label}} must be a number',
'number.greater': '{{#label}} must be greater than {{#limit}}',
'number.infinity': '{{#label}} cannot be infinity',
'number.integer': '{{#label}} must be an integer',
'number.less': '{{#label}} must be less than {{#limit}}',
'number.max': '{{#label}} must be less than or equal to {{#limit}}',
'number.min': '{{#label}} must be greater than or equal to {{#limit}}',
'number.multiple': '{{#label}} must be a multiple of {{#multiple}}',
'number.negative': '{{#label}} must be a negative number',
'number.port': '{{#label}} must be a valid port',
'number.positive': '{{#label}} must be a positive number',
'number.precision': '{{#label}} must have no more than {{#limit}} decimal places',
'number.unsafe': '{{#label}} must be a safe number'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I did it in using joi 17.6

```
VerifyAuthOtpValidator (otpProps: OtpProps) {
        const otpSchema = Joi.object<OtpProps>({
            otp_code: Joi.string().required().messages({
                "string.empty": "No OTP code provided",
                "any.required": "No OTP code provided",
            })
        });
        const {error, value} = otpSchema.validate(otpProps);
        //you can log the error property, as this would enable you
        // see the error type, which you can then, customise
        // the message
        // console.log("\n\t error: ", error)
        if(error){
            return error.message
        }
        return value
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I found was :

Create a Middleware for JOI validation

Validator.js - You can create your custom error object

```
const Joi = require('Joi');

module.exports = schema => (req, res, next) => {
  const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
  if (result.error) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      errorCause: result.error.name,
      missingParams: result.error.details[0].path,
      message: result.error.details[0].message
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

In the routes or controller pass this middleware function

```
const joiValidator = require('../utils/validator'); // Wherever you have declare the validator or middlerware

   const  userSchema = joi.object().keys({
    email : joi.string().email().required(),
    password : joi.string().required()
  });

  routes.routes('/').get(joiValidator(userSchema), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Person Check');
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

If you need an easy way to pass custom message, use [js-flex-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-flex-validator)

```js
import Flex, { validateObject } from "js-flex-validator";

const constraints = [
  Flex("username")
    .string()
    .allowEmpty()
    .min(3, "Username should be at least 3 characters")
    .max(50, "Username should not exceeds 50 characters"),
  Flex("email")
    .email("This email is not valid.")
    .match(/\w.@edu.com$/, "Should be a edu.com domain")
    .required()
    .min(5, "Email should be at least 3 characters")
    .max(255, "Username should not exceeds 255 characters"),
  Flex("password")
    .string()
    .required()
    .min(5, "Password should be at least 5 characters")
    .max(20, "Password should not exceeds 50 characters"),
];

const data = {username: "geek4", email: "example@email.com", password: "123456" };
const { hasError, errorDetails } = validateObject(data, constraints)
```