# Joi custom error message works but can't display the message properly

Tags: javascript, joi

guys. 
I am trying to validate email format by using Joi and really new to coding.

By using the following syntax, it works for me to display custom error messages.

However, the result only showed the "invalid email format" and never showed "cannot be an empty field" even I left the input empty.

```
schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string()
      .empty()
      .email()
      .error(errors => {
        errors.forEach(err => {
          switch (err.type) {
            case "any.empty":
              err.message = `cannot be an empty field`;
              break;
            case "string.email":
              err.message = `invalid email format`;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        });
        return errors;
      })
  });
```

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: As you set `.empty()`, doesn't it mean that the field can be empty ? so it will be normal that the error is not triggered

Comment: @MaximeGirou I thought .empty()  which means the input field can not be empty

Comment: From the doc : `Note that the empty string is not allowed by default`. So i guess that if you don't specify the `.empty()` it will works ?
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#string

Comment: @MaximeGirou still can't work but I appreciate :)

Comment: strange, i tried on my projects without .empty() and with your "error code", it works fine ... //

Comment: @MaximeGirou If you could share your code, I would appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202735/discussion-between-maxime-girou-and-jordantseng).

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234246/1499476