# Getting "language" is not allowed error in JOI?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, schema, joi

I recently migrated to new joi repo (@hapi/joi => joi)

Now I am getting error when running server

```
throw new AssertError([result.error.details[0].message]);
        ^

Error: "language" is not allowed
```

I searched google and SO , but cant find solution

This is my code :

```
  forgetUser: {
    query: {
      email: Joi.string().regex(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
      .required()
      .options({ language: { string: { regex: { base: 'must be valid' } } } })
      .label('Email')
    }
  },
```

Please help me?

Comment: did you find the reason? had the same issue after updating the version.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused when you are passing an unknown field to a Joi schema.

for example, you have this Joi schema:

```js
Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  email: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

and you pass this object to validate:

```js
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
  language: "en"
}
```

The validation will throw an error / failed because `language` is not allowed inside the schema.

To prevent this, you can pass `stripUnknown` options on the Joi Schema so it will strip unknown fields

```js
Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  email: Joi.string().required(),
}).options({ stripUnknown: true });
```

or you can pass `allowUnknown` so it will ignore unknown fields

```js
Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  email: Joi.string().required(),
}).options({ allowUnknown: true });
```

You can read more about validation options [here](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/v15.0.3/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback)

Comment: language is an object for option field . Not obj to validate

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear from the question what you are trying to achieve (maybe add more details?).

If you are trying to validate email, there is already a built-in function to do so: [string.email()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#stringemailoptions).

If you still want to do a custom regex matching, there is an built-in function for this too: [string.pattern()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#stringpatternregex-name--options---aliases-regex).

If you want to replace the built-in error messages to custom error messages, Joi provides that by using `.messages()`. Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234246/1499476.

---

Basically, you can do something like:

```
forgetUser: {
    query: {
      email: Joi.string().pattern(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
      .required()
      .label('Email')
      .messages({
        'string.pattern.base': '{#label} must be valid', // --> Email must be valid.
        'string.base': '{#label} should be a type of "text"',
        ... // other customisations
      })
    }
  },
```

`string.pattern()` can also be used as alias `string.regex()` (as you are already doing).