# How to validate user input nested object using JOI

Tags: node.js, express, joi

How to validate nested object using JOI in nodejs ("joi": "^17.3.0")

```
const Joi = require("joi");

const Validation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    details: {
      firstname: Joi.string().required(),
      lastname: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};

module.exports = {
  Validation,
};
```

req.body sample

```
{
    "details": {
        "firstname": "Fname",
        "lastname": "Lname"
    }
}
```

Validation(req.body)

**Error message I'm getting ""details.firstname" is required if i'm not sending firstname property. how to get proper message like "firstname required"**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js + Joi how to display a custom error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720942/node-js-joi-how-to-display-a-custom-error-messages)

Comment: Nope. my requirement is different

Comment: please accept if your question solved

Answer (score 1):

At a quick look I found out that you are missing `.keys` before the nested object so it should be like this.

```
const Joi = require("joi");

const Validation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    details: {
      firstname: Joi.string().required(),
      lastname: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};

module.exports = {
  Validation,
};
```

Also this validation will require `firstname` in the body as it is required as per your validation and if you want a custom message to show on error then it would be like this.

```
firstname: Joi.string().required().error(() => {
    return {
        message: 'Your custom message',
    };
})
```

Comment: After adding .keys still throwing same error message ("details.firstname" is required)

Comment: If your data is same as sample then it should not return this error message. If you are not passing the `firstname` in the body then this error message will be there as per your validation i-e `firstname: Joi.string().required()`. if `firstname` is not required you can change the validation to  `firstname: Joi.string()`

Comment: Joi is displaying error messages properly when sending data as object
{
      firstname: Joi.string().required(),
      lastname: Joi.string().required(),
    }

But nested objects not giving proper error messages

Comment: I don't want to write any custom messages because JOI is already giving the default messages.

Comment: If you don't want any validation errors make sure that your body looks like this `{"details":{"firstname":"Fname","lastname":"Lname"}}`

Comment: I need error messages, currently i'm getting error messages like this
"details.firstname" is required because of the nested object schema.
I want to get the error message like this "firstname" is required by following nested object schema. I don't know whether it's possible with JOI. writing custom message for every validation will be time consuming instead I can create my own validation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

To have the desired output,install joi:version 14 (`npm i joi@14`), don't install latest version,because what you want available in version 14, Then you can do like the following code

```
const Joi = require("joi");

const Validation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    details: {
      firstname: Joi.string().required(),
      lastname: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  });
  let {error} = schema.validate(data)
  const { details } = error;
  const message = details.map((i) => i.message).join(",");
  console.log("error", message);
  return message;
};

module.exports = {
  Validation,
};
```

Comment: Still I'm getting message as "details.firstname" is required. to get "firstname" is required I modified my code like this error.details[0].message.split('.')[1].
I know this is not the best solution but I don't have any other answer right now.

Comment: I edited my answer because it's correct in version 14 of joi